# ¿Cómo puedo girar una matriz en Bash?

Tags: array, bash

Tengo que hacer un array bidimensional de 3 columnas y 2 filas y mostrarlo en forma de matriz, hasta ahí todo bien. Pero luego tengo que girarlo 90 grados a la izquierda o a la derecha y ahí ya no sé cómo hacerlo.

Por ejemplo:

```
123
456
```

Girado 90 grados a la izquierda:

```
36
25
14
```

El código que tengo es:

```
#!/bin/bash 

declare -A MatrizA
declare -A MatrizB

x=0
y=0

echo Numero de columnas
read x
echo Numero de filas
read y
echo Matriz A

for((fila=0;fila<$y;fila++))
do
    for((columna=0;columna<$x;columna++))
    do
        echo Dame un numero
        read valor
        MatrizA[$columna,$fila]=$valor
    done
done

echo Matriz 1
m1=0
for((fila=0;fila<$y;fila++))
do
    mA=
    for((columna=0;columna<$x;columna++))
    do
        m1=${MatrizA[$columna,$fila]}
        mA="$mA $m1"
    done
    echo $mA
done
echo

#Array girado

m1=0
for((fila=0;fila<$y;fila++))
do
    mA=
    for((columna=0;columna<$x;columna++))
    do
        m1=${MatrizA[$columna,$fila]}
        mA="$m1 $mA"
    done
    echo $mA
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Así a bote pronto se me ocurre que Awk puede ser una buena herramienta.

Dado un fichero

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

Entonces para rotar 90º podemos hacer:

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) a[i,NR]=$i} 
     END {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
              for (j=1;j<=NR;j++) 
                  printf "%s%s", a[NF-i+1,j], (j==NR?RS:FS)
              }
         }'
```

En esencia, se trata de guardar toda la información en un vector `a[fila,columna]` y luego hacer un bucle para escribirlo todo de la forma requerida. En particular, iterar sobre el nº de columnas y luego sobre el número de filas; entonces, empezar imprimiendo la última fila y seguir hasta la primera.

En una línea:

```
$ awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) a[i,NR]=$i} END {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {for (j=1;j<=NR;j++) printf "%s%s", a[NF-i+1,j], (j==NR?RS:FS)}}' fichero
3 6
2 5
1 4
```

Si quisieras rotar 90º a la derecha, entonces solamente se trataría de modificar los índices a la hora de imprimir y decir:

```
                  printf "%s%s", a[i,NR-j+1], (j==NR?RS:FS)
```

En una línea:

```
$ awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) a[i,NR]=$i} END {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {for (j=1;j<=NR;j++) printf "%s%s", a[i,NR-j+1], (j==NR?RS:FS)}}' fichero
4 1
5 2
6 3
```

Comment: Gracias, aunque no se nada de awk, lo necesitaba en lenguaje bash

Comment: @dejay la lógica es equivalente, solamente se trata de ir modificando el índice.

Comment: Lo voy a intentar a ver, si me sale te aviso, gracias

Comment: hice algo así, pero no me sale
`for((fila=1;fila<=$nFilas;fila++))`
`do`
 `a[$fila,$nFilas]=$fila`
 `for((fila=1;fila<=$nFilas;fila++))`
 `do`
 `for((columna=1;columna<=$nFilas;columna++))`
 `do`
  `echo a[$fila-$i+1,$columna]`
 `done`
 `done`
`done`
Me imprime esto
`a[1-+1,1]`
`a[1-+1,2]`
`a[2-+1,1]`
`a[2-+1,2]`

No se como hacerlo, le doy mil vueltas pero no le pillo la lógica